# Change navigation url depending on mobile or desktop css

Tags: php, jquery, css, url, linker

When my site is using the mobile css the navigation becomse so long, that the user dose not  see the conctent unless they scroll down.

I then want to change the navigations urs to link to divs so it's jumps right down to the content

exsampel:

When @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) is in use the navigations links have the url

site1.php#content

site2.php#content

site3.php#content

When @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) is in use

site1.php

site2.php

site3.php

How should i do this? PHP og jQuery ?

I lookt at this code:

```
$("a[href^='http://stackoverflow.com']")
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/beta\.stackoverflow\.com/, 
         "http://stackoverflow.com");
   });
```

Will it be possible to modify this in a way so it wil work i my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the name of the element that you wish for the page to scroll to, we can do.

```
$(function(){
    var hash = (window.location.hash) ? window.location.hash : null;
    if(null !== hash){
        //now I don't know how the markup is designed, so we'll just use `id`
        $(window).scrollTop($('[id='+hash+']').scrollTop());
    }
});
```

On page load, we create a variable called `hash`, we see if the `hash` is present, if it is, we use the hash value, otherwise, we null it. In our conditional, we tell the window to scroll until the window reaches the to of the element we define as the value, which for our example, is the `id` of an element `matching the hash value`.

Now, I don't know how you generate the variable `content`, there must be some attribute within your `<a>` element that contains the value you want. If you show me how you plan to reference the element, I will connect the missing links.

**Edit** -- in response to your comment.

```
$('.main-menu a').prop('href', function(a,b){
    return b+'#content';
});
```

[Here's your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugzup/) -- Check the console so you don't have to waste time in specting.

**Edit #2** -- In response to mobile detection.

Instead of using media queries, I use user agent sniffing. It's a pretty common technique. The guys over at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ provide a script we can use to check the user agent for the presence of **many** known and popular mobile devices.

[Check the jsFiddle out over here](http://jsfiddle.net/kPd5J/).

Simply take the large block of code and place it in a flie like `mobileDetect.js'.

Anything below the `//comments` is an implementation of the code I've written above, and is placed accordingly in the conditional statement. I tested this on a few devices, and it works well.

Comment: But how do i detect with css is in use? I only want the #content added when it is mobile deviceses coming to the page.

Comment: Wow it works! Thats owsome, Thanks a lot! But the #content only gets added on the first time i click a link.

Comment: @Kasper Can you elaborate? I"m a little confused.

Comment: When i loaded the page and click on one of the links it jumps to the div #content and put the #content behind the url. but if i then scroll back up and click on another link it dose not jump to the #content and the #content is not added behind the url

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it to work!..

I replace

```
$('.main-menu a').prop('href', function(a,b){
    return b+'#content';
});
```

to this:

```
$(function () {

     $('.main-menu a').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href + '#content');
});
 });
```